# Complex analysis tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging, tag-synonyms

I recently became aware of the fact that we have these overlapping tags:

- [complex](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complex)
- [complex-analysis](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complex-analysis)

The [complex](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complex) (211 questions) covers complex analysis as well as all aspects of complex numbers.
The [complex-analysis](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complex-analysis) (37 questions) seems self-explanatory to me; about half are also tagged [complex](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complex) as well.

Shouldn't these be synonyms?  If so, would the main tag be [complex](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complex), it being more general?

Comment: I hesitated merging these two when I first encountered them, but now that I think about it, it could work if complex analysis questions were tagged with both [tag:complex] and [tag:calculus-and-analysis].

Comment: I like @Guesswhoitis. suggestion as it defines the questions as being part of a larger system, not solely a "complex" issue.

Comment: @Guess That sounds good to me too.  Would you post that as an answer so that it can be voted for and possibly accepted?

Comment: BTW: if you finish the *en masse* retag, please ping me or any of the other mods so we can merge and synonymize.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. Done. Synonymize away. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As requested:

If indeed we decide to merge [complex](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complex) and [complex-analysis](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complex-analysis), we should first make sure that the appropriate questions have already been tagged with both [complex](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complex) and [calculus-and-analysis](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculus-and-analysis). This might take a while. I would suggest volunteer retaggers to do it gradually over the course of a few days so as not to overwhelm the front page.

Comment: I like this idea, too. +1.  I assume I should wait until there is a consensus-quorum to accept -- that's really a question, I guess.  I don't quite know the protocol.

Comment: Does this constitute a consensus yet?

Comment: I think so; nobody seems to be vehemently objecting. Retag away! :)

Comment: Salamat! Thanks! (needed 15 chars)